# Trouble converting jpeg image to the correct byte array

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax

I was trying to send some data through a SOAP service call. Currently I am having issue to send the correct image data format(or maybe some other issues I am not aware).

I am using laptop webcam to take a photo and pass the `jpeg` data to my back-end through `ajax` call and successful. The JavaScript library I am using is from here:

https://github.com/jhuckaby/webcamjs

After taking the photo, I am sending the picture to the back end so in the `$.ajax` i did this:

```
data : JSON.stringify({imageData : data})
```

On my java side, I grabbed the imageData by converting it from String to `byte[]`:

```
String imageData = jsonObj.getString("imageData");
byte[] finalImage = imageData.getBytes();
```

The problem I am having right now is if I send this `finalImage` byte array to the SOAP service call, I got an error respond saying the file is either missing or too large(over 1mb). I did a `finalImage.length` and it returns 7120. So I think the file is definitely not over 1mb in terms of size.

I created a `test.jpeg` file from my Windows OS using Snipping Tool and did the following and the SOAP service happily accepted, the length of the `testImage` byte array is 7884 is:

```
File fi = new File("test.jpeg");
byte[] testImage= Files.readAllBytes(fi.toPath());
```

What could be the reason? The file not in the correct format?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think its possible that an Image File would weight 7kb... Something is wrong in here... Perhaps check the file if anything is wrong with it or something like that.